# Clarifcation on counting Vowels using Recursion in Java

Tags: java, recursion

I'm in need of clarification for one of my homework questions;
as it states to *"implement a recursive method to count and return the total number of lower case vowels in the given string"* to make it easier, assume that there's a helping method (let's call it isVowel(ch)) which returns *true* if the given character is a lower case vowel and false otherwise.

So: `isVowel(ch)` returns `true` if character is a lower case vowel and false otherwise

so for the first question it asks identify a suitable stopping case:

```
public static int cVowels (String s)
    if (s.length() == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Is this correct?

Next question it asks to implement the method recursively and create code that returns the number of lower case vowels in given string s. This is where we assume that there is a helping method isVowel(ch). (Kinda stuck here)

```
public static int cVowels (String s) {
    if (s.length() == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        int counter = cVowels(s.substring(1));
        if (isVowel(s.charAt(0)) == true) {
            return 1+counter;
        } else 
            return counter;
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone clarify if the code is indeed correct? If not, where is the problem? Having trouble testing it because the assumed helper methods.

Thanks

Comment: Frankly I think a nice loop would easily solve this and be more readable. But if your assignment demands recursion, you could reduce the number of times the method is repeated by looping through the string and stopping at the first variable found, then calling the method again removing the section that's already been searched. Otherwise, I agree with tobias.

Comment: Yep the work demands recursion, and sorry about the indentation, as I wrote the code straight from my paper onto the site, I missed a few things which I'll fix now.

Comment: Add your own `isVowel` method for testing, and remove it before handing in the exercise. Do you know how to write one?

Comment: @RealSkeptic Will have a go at it now.

Comment: You also need some way of maintaining the values through recursion, since [Java is pass by value](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm). The easiest is to use a use a class variable, but you can also pass an object wrapper around a counter  variable through your recursion levels

Comment: @user3437460 not difficult, was just trying to save time I guess, figured in the end it's just best to test it out.

Comment: @user3437460, vowels are not **all** lowercase alphabet chars :), its only 5 letters. This would work `return "aeiou".indexOf(myChar) >= 0`

Comment: @nem Woops. In that case, he can do this: `return Character.toString(ch).matches("[aeiou]");` Your looks good too.

Comment: `return (isVowel(s.charAt(0)) ? 1 : 0) + cVowels(s.substring(1));` is a terser way for writing the else branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question the logic looks sound. This isn't how I would have approached the problem, but it looks like it would work nevertheless. You're essentially checking for vowels from the end of the string moving left to the start but whatever floats your boat.

You can easily write a helper method to test this, it should look something like this for a beginner learning basic concepts:

```
public static boolean isVowel (char ch) {
    if (ch=='a' || 
        ch=='e' ||
        ch=='i' ||
        ch=='o' ||
        ch=='u') 
    {
        return true;
    } else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, was writing a more extensive isVowel method and this saved me some time to test out the code (which was correct).  Also, what way would you approach this, if you don't mind me asking.